# Checkboxes to SQL in ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, checkbox, data-binding

I have an existing MS SQL table with data and need to add a new column to SQL that should store the value from a single checkbox field in a HTML form using ASP.NET Core 5 and razorpages

here are my questions

- What data type should I use in SQL for this checkbox column?
- What data type should I use in the Model?
- What values should be stored in SQL, "false/true", 0/1, -1,0  ?

as a side note I can say I have tried many differrent options but I endup all the time getting some kind of type missmatch error when I submit my form, or when I try to bind the value to the checkbox in an "editform"

thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the SQL `bit` datatype if your data is boolean (True or False) which a checkbox will be.

Data type in the model should be `bool`.

The value stored in SQL is 1 or 0.

The issue is likely with the code you are using to bind your model to the checkbox element on your page.

If you can share some of the code/razor markup that you are using then might be able to be of more help..

[This](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes) should be helpful.

Comment: thanks. if I change the data type to bit in sql, and set model to bool,  all column rows now contain 'False' and when I try to load/display all the rows I now get: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean'. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Boolean()

Comment: Although SQL Server is storing the values as a single bit (0 or 1), management studio will display this as 'True' or 'False'.  You have defined your column with Default(0) so value will be 0 or 'False' by default.  What configuration do you have applied to your model? Do you have anything in OnModelCreating? If so, could you share this?